# how to add new files to edx fullstack so that it could work locally

Tags: edx, openedx

I want to add some HTML5 to my edx course. Where should I put my .html, .css and .js files so that they can work locally

Comment: I want to know the location in vagrant box

Comment: i can tell you location but i am using bitnami openedx installer.File configurations are same.

Comment: okay. could you please tell me the location

Answer (score 1):

If you add a file to `/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/static`, for example `pouac.js`, it will be available at http://youlmsdomainname.com/static/pouac.js once you re-collect the static assets. [This is how](http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-developer-guide/en/latest/pavelib.html#assets) you collect assets:

```
paver update_assets lms
```

Answer (score 0):

All the .html, .js, and .css files are located in static folder for each cms & lms directory.
Now you want to add some html5 to your edx course so you have to edit htmls  of lms & particular courseware htmls.

Please keep in mind that some blocks are made of js in htmls. So you have to look into some js files that are rendered later as html.

If you want to add new pages to lms or studio you have to follow below documentation.
[doc link](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TNL/How+to+add+a+new+page+to+LMS+or+Studio)

Hope this will help or shoot any query in comment.